# How do I keep a command executed by QProcess when the process ends?

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, qprocess

I'm trying to find a way to keep the commands executed by `QProcess` after GUI program is terminated in Linux system. Now, when the process ends, all the commands executed are gone. Is there a way to keep that after `QProcess` is terminated?

```
// code which executes command in linux
QProcess *mproc = new Qprocess(this);
QStringList args;
mproc->setWorkingDirectory("/home/test");
args << "-c" << "source tool_def1.env; source tool_def2.env; myProg";
mproc->start("/bin/csh", args);
```

The `tool_def1.env` and `tool_def2.env` file are included some environment variables for executing `myProg`, like `set path = (~~~~)`.

In GUI Program, this code is well done. And, I want to execute `myProg` program in terminal which GUI program is run after GUI program is terminated.

But, if GUI Program is terminated, I can't run `myProg` because the environment variables of `tool_def1.env` and `tool_def2.env` file is disappear.

Is it possible to keep the environment variables? Or, is it possible to execute `myProg` program in other process with environment variables of `mproc` process as following?

```
QProcess *mproc2 = new QProcess(this);
mproc2->setWorkingDirectory("/home/test2");
mproc2->start("myProg");
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached

Comment: Thank you, scopchanov. I've tried to use startDetached, but it does not work well. In my GUI Program, it works good. But, when the GUI Program is running or terminated, 'myProg' can not be found in terminal yet. Also, 'mproc2' process doesn't work. I've only exchanged 'start' to 'startDetached' in my code. Is it right??

Comment: Couple of questions to check: Are you sure the return of the startDetached is true? Did you check the PID that is returned? Are you sure it keeps running? (maybe write some log file which you can examine)

Comment: I checked the return of the startDetached is true and 'myProg' is work well. But, after I closed GUI Program and 'myProg', then, when I execute myProg again in shell prompt of terminal, myProg is not work and 'command not found' message is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The overload of [`QProcess::startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) you are using is a static method, so it will not take into consideration attributes of particular instances, i.e., `mproc->setWorkingDirectory("/home/test")` doesn't set the working directory for the static method, only for `mproc`. When you launch the process, as the working directory is not set for the static call, the program cannot be found and it fails.

As you can see in the documentation, the static `startDetached` also admits the working directory as a parameter, so you can change your code to:

```
QStringList args;
args << "-c" << "source tool_def1.env; source tool_def2.env; myProg";
QProcess::startDetached("/bin/csh", args, "/home/test");
```

Another way is using the non-static version, which requires the program to be specified separately:

```
QProcess mproc(this);

QStringList args;
args << "-c" << "source tool_def1.env; source tool_def2.env; myProg";
mproc.setArguments(args);

mproc.setWorkingDirectory("/home/test");
mproc.setProgram("/bin/csh");

qint64 pid; // to store the process ID (will become invalid if the child process exits)
mproc.startDeatached(&pid);
```

Regarding your second question, take a look at [`QProcess::setProcessEnvironment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment). Just that you'll have to use the non-static way to set the environment of the process. You can get the environment variables of the current process using [`QProcess::systemEnvironment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#systemEnvironment).

```
mproc.setProcessEnvironment(QProcess::systemEnvironment());
```

Update from comments: if you want to always use the environment variables active when the GUI application was running (is it some kind of configurator?) you can just save them to a file (a JSON for example), then load and set them manually from the second process.

To extract them, you can do something like:

```
const auto env_vars = QProcess::systemEnvironment().toStringList();
```

Now `env_vars` will be a list of strings with format `NAME_OF_ENVAR=VALUE_OF_ENVAR`. You can save such list to the file (you will need to prepend an `export` at the beginning of each line to be usable with `source`).

---

I've tested the static version in Windows (VS 15.8.2 and Qt 5.10.0) and it worked as expected. Code used:

```
#include <qprocess.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QProcess::startDetached("cmd", QStringList() << "/c" << "test.exe", "../test/");

  return 0;
}
```

where *test.exe*'s code is basically a never ending process.

---

*Note*: An interesting fact, and as a note for developer using VS. For the same program and build, if it is executed from the command line it works correctly: application ends and the second process keeps running in the background, but if executed from the VS IDE then the *console window* keeps alive, and if I close it, the the second process is killed too. When debugged, the debugger ends but the console is still shown. I suppose it is because VS somehow *tracks* all created processes when launched from the IDE.

Comment: Thank you. But my problem is not solved yet. I want to execute 'myProg' program again after GUI Program is closed, not to keep running 'myProg' program which executed during running GUI Program. After both GUI Program and 'myProg' are terminated, then, I hope that 'myProg' is executed again when I input 'myProg' (execution command) in shell prompt in terminal window. So I want to keep the environment variables after GUI Program terminated. Is it possible that?

Comment: I don't understand: you want to execute myProg but close it when the GUI ends, then resume it manually from a shell, but using the environment variables present during the execution of the GUI? In such case just save them to a file (JSON, XML, INI...), and reload them when executing from shell. For example, from GUI you can add a command-line parameter to indicate EV must be stored, and if omitted (as from CLI) then load them from the file. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes!!  But, I don't know well about JSON, XML, INI, CLI... Is it possible to apply the env. variables to terminal in GUI Program???

Comment: Use any file format you want to write/read, they were just examples (although I encourage you to learn them, since they are very useful)... CLI stands for: Command Line Interface (shell)

Comment: The file already exists for applying the env variables. (tool_def1.env / tool_def2.env) And, I can also run 'myProg' by typing 'source' in terminal. However, I want to reuse the same variable once applied to the GUI program, not sourcing them again. Is it possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that case, just overwrite your files with the environment variables as indicated in the answer. If you want to exclude some vars or want to split them in two files, then you have to do it manually (filtering the vars, take a look at all the methods of [`QProcessEnvironment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you!! There seems to be no way to automatically apply environment variables used in GUI programs to terminals.I will try to do as you explained. And I think I should study more about the systemEnvironment(). Thanks for your help. It was a lot of help.